Why don't we apply the principle of indifference here?
The Problem
You and a friend play a game where you both select an integer $1-100$:

The winner receives $\$ 1$ from the loser.
The winner is the one who chooses a number that is either

exactly two less than the other player's number
or strictly greater than the other player's number ( if they choose a number that is two less than your, they win ).



Assume you and your friend play optimally:
What is the optimal strategy here, and what is $\operatorname{Var}\left(X\right)$, where $X$ is the random value you choose according to this optimal distribution ?.
My Questions
(i) I haven't yet been exposed to too many of these questions regarding "optimal strategies". So I'm a little unsure on how to think when I see one. Are these really probability questions? If so, can someone tell me in a general way how I should think about these kinds of problems?
(ii) The only question I've seen that was similar to this one (in that it was an "optimal strategy" question as well) was the popular problem 3.4 in Mark Joshi's book (Fail to understand 'The indifference criterion means that $1p_1=2p_2=3p_3$.'). It utilized the indifference criterion. Why can't the same principle be applied here? What's different between that problem and this problem?
In case you don't know which problem I'm talking about, I will reproduce it here:
We play a game: I pick a number from 1 to 100. If you guess correctly, I pay you $n and zero otherwise. How much would you pay to play this game?

Let me start by first answering the last question that you gave; even if you already know the answer to it, I think it helps to walk through the solution step by step to make sure we’re on the same page about indifference.
For the time being, let’s assume number selections are from a uniform distribution- you randomly pick a number from 1-100, then my best response is to always pick 100. Why? Well because I have the same probability of getting any number correct with probability $\frac{1}{100}$ and my payout is linear with the number so my goal here is to maximize the number that I select; the EV of my choice is simply $\frac{n}{100}$ so I maximize my choice of $n$. This can be generalized for any range of $n_i$ to $n_j$. However, it is clear that when $n_i$ does not equal 1, that is not optimal play for you.
Now, based on the fact that you brought up the concept of indifference, you can probably already see the flaw in selecting the numbers from a uniform distribution. I clearly have a best response and therefore am not indifferent to the number that I choose. What if I was indifferent to which number I picked? In order for that to be the case, $n * P(n)$ must be equal for every $n$ where $P(n)$ is the probability of you selecting $n$. Because my payout is linear with $n$ increasing, $P(n)$ must be linearly decreasing proportionately for indifference. In other words, you should select 1 with probability 100 times greater than you select 100, 2 with probability 50 times greater than you select 100, ….
We eventually arrive that your optimal distribution: $P(n) = \frac{\frac{100}{n}}{\frac{100(100+1)}{2}} = \frac{100}{n5050}$
I am now indifferent to which number I select and my expected payout is always $\frac{100}{5050}$ regardless of which number I pick.
Back to the original question:
A basic assumption of game theory problems is that all players are rational agents, every participant will play optimally. This game is symmetrical with regard to information so two rational agents must therefore play the exact same way otherwise they do not have optimal play by contradiction.
For the problem, any pure strategy is obviously exploitable by the other participant. If that’s not immediately clear, just think about how you can guarantee a win if you knew for certain what your opponent picked. We’ve now seen how this game clearly has a mixed Nash Equilibrium.
Suppose you knew that I was always going to pick a number randomly, well your best response is to always pick 100 as you have a 98% chance of picking a higher number where mine is not 2 less than yours and only a 1% chance of a tie and a 1% chance of a loss (when I randomly pick 98). We now see how the distribution needs to be skewed higher so that picking the highest number does not exploit our own strategy.
Perhaps a slight leap in logic, but what if I were to pick 100 with probability $p$ and 98 with probably $1-p$? Now what is your best response? Well clearly it is dependent on $p$ here. We now need to find a $p$ such that you do not have a way to exploit this. But also, we can see that for any $p$ here, my response is exploitable because one could respond with 98 every time. We therefore need to mix in 99 with some probability. So when are you indifferent? When do you not know with any confidence that I am picking one over the others? When each is picked $\frac{1}{3}$ of the time of course. Your best response is therefore to mirror my strategy so that you do not become exploitable yourself.
Final Answer: The optimal strategy is to pick between 98, 99, and 100 independently and randomly. This is just another way to represent rock, paper, scissors.
